# How to process annotation on any Instance without express call

Tags: java, annotations

I’m new to JavaAnnotation so my question is when processing annotion like...

```
void process(Object object) { ... }
```

ie knowing the instance on witch we'll process annotation...

How to process annotation such a way there is no need to call `.process(ourInstance)` ourself, after each instanciation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do said process every single time you instantiate something you can simply put it into said object's constructor.

```
public final TestObject() {
    process(this); // <- this sends this instance of the object into process
}
```

this assumes that process is a public or private method within this class.

Comment: You should never let 'this' go outside of the constructor scope as the object may not be fully initialized yet.

Comment: I am assuming here that the things that have to be initialized are already initialized before calling process, but you are right about that

Comment: Absolutely but I want to share the code as API or Framework, then the user just have to annotate fields or method, but doesn't have to write any code of how they will be triggered

Comment: @kolsyrad So at the very least make the class final. Otherwise you cannot be sure that everything is already initialized because there might be a subclass.

Comment: @R4J I see your point and agree with you, I was trying to make it as simple as possible but confusion may so have arisen, thanks for the comments. I've made it final.